# Error while installation of apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M26 on windows 8

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

I'm trying to install tomcat 9 on my windows 8, but the following error arose all the times [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dt8mY.png)
 I tried to install it on C: inside Program Files\Java, inside C:\master.. and inside E:\java\ 
I add the JAVA_HOME, JRE_HOME, Classpath, CATALINA_HOME in the environmental variables like this:

```
CATALINA_HOME=e:\Java\apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M26
JAVA_HOME= C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111
JRE_HOME= C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_144
ClassPath=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%JRE_HOME%\bin;%CATALINA_HOME%\lib
```

tomcat folder was located in c and then in e because if the permission was limited to the server but the same error arose as shown in the image. Is there any solutions?

[image]

Comment: Microsoft Windows [Version 6.2.9200]
(c) 2012 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

>C:\Users\XXXX>e:

>E:\>cd Java\apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M26\bin

>E:\Java\apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M26\bin>set java_home
JAVA_HOME=(value = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111)

>E:\Java\apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M26\bin>set jre_home
JRE_HOME=(value = C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_144)

>E:\Java\apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M26\bin>startup
The JRE_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
This environment variable is needed to run this program
>E:\Java\apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M26\bin>

Comment: please edit your question with the data that you've added as a comment and format them accordingly. As a comment it's quite unreadable.

Comment: It is the string written in the cmd window. I added the image but I can't see it, so that I wrote all what is written in.

Answer (score 0):

Wherever you get that bracket and value stuff from: get rid of it. JAVA_HOME or JRE_HOME need to resolve to just and exactly a directory. Pardon my missing Windows foo, but `cd %JAVA_HOME%` (alternatively try $JAVA_HOME or leave out the trailing %) must result in that directory to be the current directory.

This *(value=* stuff and the closing brace have no business in being there.

You can define proper values in tomcat bin/setenv.bat (you might need to create that file, it will be used automatically when it's there)

Comment: I tried all that but unfortunately it does not work. Thank you

Comment: Please post the new values and rote messages

Answer (score 0):

The error was because of some problems, first I defined the environment variables as user variables where I had to define them as system variables. 
[image]
Then the xml files in the conf folder should be modified according to the step three mentioned in this link: [here](https://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/Tomcat_HowTo.html#zz-2.3)
After that, the CMD must be run as administrator